# How to use two different Web applications from two different AD forests with same domain sso account

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, websphere, weblogic

We have two different applications running on two different Active Directory Forests. APP1 is running on IBM Websphere application server on Forest 1, APP2 is running on Weblogic application server on Forest 2.
Both apps authenticated (SSO) against their AD.

We need users to use both apps on single account from single workstation.

How this can be accomplished?

We are thinking to implement Forest trust between two forests.